# The button doesn't update by click

Tags: jquery

I have the simple JS code for updating text on button:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border='1'>
    <div id="load-button" style="border:1px solid black; background-color:white;padding:5px;cursor:pointer;width:200px;text-align:center;border-radius:4px;">Load button</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //wait for HTML document
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#load-button').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
              url: 'http://developers-blog.org/resources/jquery-ajax/snippet.html',
              success: function(data) {
                $('#load-button').empty();
                $('#load-button').append(data); 
              }
            });
          });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

JQuery library is the folder with index.php page. But this code doesn't work. Please, tell me, where have I made a mistake? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd start with cleaning up your markup, as it's invalid.

Comment: @TiesonT. You didn't like the script or the div inside the table? I think it's cute!

Comment: What in hell is that `table` doing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you are making a cross domain request and most browsers by default enforce a **[SAME ORIGIN POLICY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)** and block requests to other domains.. You can use jsonp or use your server to contact the paritcular end point.. read more about JSONP here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a case where the Same Domain Policy is applied.

In case you have access to the files on the server that you want to call, you can set a header  (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) on the application to allow the request from determined domains.

PHP example:

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

or

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://permitted_domain.com');`